# How to use while loop with range

Tags: python

I have used tkinter to create an asking question messagebox and there are `yes` and `no` to choose.

I would like to know how to perform clicking 5 times `no` then it will show error.

I tried using while loop but after clicking `no` one time it didn't show error messagebox.

Below is my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter import messagebox

count = 5

def love():
    ok = messagebox.showwarning(title='WARNING', message='HAHA')
    if (ok == "ok"):
            while count:
               answer = messagebox.askquestion(title='name', message='Who?')

               if(answer == 'yes'):
                    messagebox.showwarning(title='WARNING', message='HAHAAH')
                    break
               else:
                    count-=1
                    messagebox.showwarning(title='WARNING', message='Are you sure')
                    continue
window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x100")
button = Button(window, command=love, text='Click me')
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't check if `count` has reached `0` anywhere in your code.

Comment: count is initialized outside the scope of the method. If you want to use a global variable in a function, you must redeclare it in the function with global keyword, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couple of things to do (as per the comments to the question).

- put an if statement into the else block to check `if count==0`.
- move `count=5` into the function to that it is scoped correctly.

if you are going to use the method with a while loop, the something like this works:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter import messagebox




def love():
    count = 5

    ok = messagebox.showwarning(title='WARNING', message='Your Mac has been hacked! HAHA! Answer a few questions to get your Mac back!')
    if (ok == "ok"):
        answer = messagebox.askquestion(title='Who are you?', message='Are you a human?')
        while count:
            if(answer == 'yes'):
                messagebox.showwarning(title='WARNING', message='Your Mac has been hacked! HAHA! Answer a few questions to get your Mac back!')
                break
            else:
                count-=1
                messagebox.showwarning(title='WARNING', message='Are you sure')
                if count == 0:
                    print('you clicked no 5 times !!!')
                continue
        
    
window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x100")
button = Button(window, command=love, text='Click me')
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Additional comment:

The general code does not actually ask 5 yes or no questions (it shows the ok button 5 times after the first no is clicked), but the above sets you on the correct track...

Comment: Thank u for your answer, it works. and also thank you for your additional comment, I have edited the code to make sure it asks 5 times yes or no question.